# "Answers that don't include explanations may be removed": in what cases?

Tags: discussion

I saw this [warning](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/1245/43):

> Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

In what cases are answers that don't include explanation removed?

[image]

Comment: The answer contains a block quote with a link. I'm guessing that this prompted the warning, because the quote itself is not explained - generally a policy of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @HDE226868 So in what cases such answers are removed here? (most SE websites are fine with unexplained quotes.)

Comment: Most, really? At least on SO it's not recommended. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers that's a part of the FAQ and while it mostly deals with "link only" answers, answers that just contain all link and a quote from it have the same problem of not act providing context

Comment: And from the help center: "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own". If there are no "own words" that clearly isn't the case http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @YviDe yes link-only is not ok, but quote is. My question asks about quote-only answers.

Answer (score 3):

The Stackexchange [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) has this to say about using sources in answers:

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas **to support your own**.

Emphasis mine.

If there are no words other than the quote, that clearly isn't the case.

Also, it isn't very far from a link-only answer, which [are not recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) (the linked discussion on Meta.SE being part of the FAQ).

Here's another meta discussion on the issue: [Is copying documentation bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251073/is-copying-documentation-bad/251075). I agree with the answer by Air:

> That said, if your answer consists of nothing more than a direct quote, take a moment before you hit "Submit" to consider:
>
> - Does this quote clearly contain all the information needed to solve the problem?
> - Can I add some clarifying details, perhaps an example, that would make this answer much more useful than just a quote?

Personally, I am not a mod, but I think the linked answer doesn't sufficiently address the posed question. That it's just a quote was one problem, but not the only. I use a lot of quotes in my answers, but answers need to be personalized to the question and quotes only answers usually can't fulfill that. Answers that don't answer the question [may be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: So in what cases are quote-only answers deleted?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't understand the question, or at least not when it's directed at me. An answer if it has a score of less than 0 and has three votes for deletion or if a mod deletes it. What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to "In what cases are answers that don't include explanation removed by moderators?".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt so, it's just a question for the moderators?

Comment: Moderation policy is (at least should be) public knowledge. So anyone aware of it could answer.